Can't select or edit certain parts of my mesh during retopo
I was working on a retopo for a model when I suddenly noticed some vertices and faces could no longer be selected or edited. I can grab them in sculpt mode but not in edit mode. I've tried using H and Alt+H but it doesn't help. Even tried using P to separate and possibly reveal hidden points but that doesn't help either. I would just restart but I want to know where I went wrong in this process. I have a recording and the file here in G drive

Your problem here is that you have enabled Retopology under Mesh Edit Mode Overlays > Shading and set the Offset to 0 m (default is 0.2 m).
This way Blender cannot "see" obstructed vertices (even though you can see them because of the In Front viewport option, more about it further down). If you disable the high res mesh  "Cube.005" in the viewport you can easily select vertices on the retopo mesh.
But since I guess you want to keep it visible there are two options: either disable the Retopology overlay completely or set a value > 0 m, for example 0.1 m would be enough.

It is absolutely not necessary to set a very low value or even 0 m, because this does not mean that your vertices are offset that much from the surface - it is a Shading overlay, not a mesh displacement. And by the way, since you have In Front enabled in the Obejct Properties > Viewport Display, the Retopology shading is redundant - or to be more precise: the Retopology offset actually works against the In Front setting so that a too low value will prevent vertices from being selectable although they would be with the In Front option. So you only need it if the mesh is obstructed by something and you do not want to use In Front - but then a value of 0 m would not help anything.
In Front disabled and Retopology offset = 0 m (this is how Blender "sees" the vertices which is why you cannot select them although they are visible to you when In Front is enabled):

In Front disabled and Retopology offset = 0.1 m:

So when you are using In Front, you could do without the Retopology overlay, however this will always show the mesh through other objects, for example if you look at the head from behind. With Retopology this only happens with a high offset.
In Front enabled:

In Front disabled, Retopology offset = 0.1 m:

In Front disabled, Retopology offset = 0.4 m:

